# Insufficient privilege to copy or manage ACLs for some databases in Domino Server as a Full Access Administrator

Tags: copy, acl, lotus-domino, replicate

I am a Full Access administrator as well as all other kinds of administrators (Administrators, Database Administrators etc.) except the restrictive groups such as Restricted System Administrator.

With this privilege I imagine I would be able to copy or manage ACLs for any database I want but for some I get errors. When I try to manage ACLs for some database files, I get this error popup message: `You have insufficient privilege to observe User Access for this database` and when I try to copy, I get `You are not authorized to replicate or copy data from this database.`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very simple...

I noticed that I can only perform these actions on databases with specific templates, while the ones with other templates I could not.

However all I had to do is in the Domino Administrator program, **go to the Administration tab at the very top and check the `Full Access Administration` option.** After this I could replicate and manage ACLs for any database.